# Unable to use react-toolbox component in my react.js application

Tags: .net, reactjs, gulp, browserify

My app's background - it's an ASP 5 ('vNext', MVC 6). The project is using Visual Studio 2015 with the integrated use of gulp to re-generate my client scripts, with browserify and gulp.

So I have a '.jsx' source file with require stmts, like:

```
var DatePicker = require('react-toolbox/lib/date_picker');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

...and i run it through browserify and everything is resolved as expected. I know it's resolving because if i change any of the require stmts to something invalid i see the browserify error in the task runner console in VS. I've stripped everything out of the page and just have a script tag with a reference to my bundled app.

So it finds all of the sources OK. And if I run a dead-simple html page that references my bundled script *without* any references to the DatePicker component it loads fine.

As soon as I try to use the DatePicker component, though, I get a react error:

`React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number.     It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite  components). Check the render method of 'Dashboard'.`

However, i set a breakpoint in the browser just before the use of the 'DatePicker' component and re-load to inspect the state, and 'DatePicker' is a fully instantiated, normal object available to the script at that point. I can inspect it and see that its prototype is 'ReactComponent' and that it has the methods you would expect it to {render, isMounted, etc}.

So it's not null at all. I can't understand the error being thrown when it seems as if everything is right at run-time. Of course I'm afraid it may be a function of how I'm browserify-ing and bundling, but this is all new to me so i'm not sure what to even try.

Here's my entire JSX srouce before bundling:

```
var DatePicker = require('react-toolbox/lib/date_picker');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


var Dashboard = React.createClass({
   render: function () {
       return (

     <div>
        <DatePicker />
      </div>

     );
   }
});

ReactDOM.render(
   React.createElement(
      Dashboard, {}),
      document.getElementById ("dashReactRoot")
   );
```

...and here's the pertinent gulp task:

```
gulp.task('b-fy-dashboard', function () {
   gulp.src(paths.react + '/Admin/Profile/Dashboard.jsx')
        .pipe(browserify({
           insertGlobals: false,
           bundleExternal: true,
           debug: false,
           transform: [
            ['browserify-css']
           ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + 'js/modules'));
});
```

...how is it that i can't get even the most basic use of a third-party component to work?!?! i've been at it for hours, please share any thoughts or experiences you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Could possibly be that you don't have CSS Modules configured.

See their prerequisite docs:

> React Toolbox uses CSS Modules by default to import stylesheets
>   written in SASS. In case you want to import the components already
>   bundled with CSS, your module bundler should be able to require these
>   SASS modules.
>
> Although we recommend webpack, you are free to use whatever module
>   bundler you want as long as it can compile and require SASS files
>   located in your node_modules. If you are experiencing require errors,
>   make sure your configuration satisfies this requirement.

I see that you have `browserify-css` plugged in, but it doesn't look like it supports CSS Modules.  I may be wrong here though, I am a webpack guy so I am taking a stab at this.

Here is a CSS modules plugin for Browserify: 
https://github.com/css-modules/css-modulesify

Comment: I very much appreciate the lead. I'll investigate your link and info. How much effort would it be to make the switch to webpack, in rough terms? does it integrate with gulp? and would i also have to switch to the ECMA 6/TypeScript syntax? I can see switching to webpack if all i really need to do is change my gulpfile somewhat, but not if i need to change dozens of source files i already have written.

Comment: It's quite a big switch.  I wouldn't recommend that for the sake of your projects progress. Rather take some of your spare time to learn the concepts before committing. SurviveJS has a [great series of lessons](https://survivejs.com/) - I learned from them first. Also Kent C. Dodds is going to release a new egghead series, so stay tuned there too.  Try it out, it's super powerful once you have conquered the core concepts.